# Best encoding with a C# website (UTF-8, UTF-16) - Bandwith

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

I'm going develop a website with C# (ASP.NET technology), MySQL, etc.

I've a limited bandwith in my VPS, and with UTF-8 encoding I will obtain the double bandwith instead of use UTF-16.

Should I convert ever string (and for print integers, How?) of C# to UTF-8 (it isn't a beatiful code) for my web and SQL queries (I will specify MySQL will use UTF-8)?

Comment: Yeah, but... The HTTP compression with UTF-16 will use more space :). In addition, What enconding will use the SQL DB?

Comment: Just set the encoding on the Response object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096125/context-response-charset-encoding-utf8-tostring

Comment: As far as the DB, that depends on your database provider, etc. However, I would *only* use the encoding supported by your provider, even if this means "wasted space" (i.e. with SQL Server). It will be much less painful in the end to not fight the system.

Comment: mm... Then I will specify that the HTML document uses UTF-8, and I will use C# (by default: UTF-16), and the SQL tables will use UTF-16?
For a big database, UTF-16 is a... (double space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET uses UTF-8 by default.

.NET strings are always UTF-16 in implementation, but UTF-8 is the default used when moving to and from the streams used in HTTP.

MySQL above 4.1 defaults to using UTF-8.

The encoding is well-supported.

If you had a very heavy use of characters what were larger in UTF-8 than UTF-16, then it might make some slight sense to favour UTF-16 in the places where the defaults where UTF-8, but bear in mind that those with special meaning in HTML are almost all in the U+0000–U+007F range (one octet in UTF-8) and those that take up more octets in UTF-8 than UTF-16 are mostly Asian ideographics which are very concise, resulting in there being a larger percentage of tags-to-content when in HTML than with e.g. English. As such, even when you might expect UTF-16 to be smaller, it often still won't be that much smaller.

Really, there's no good reason for ever using anything other than UTF-8 in HTML, XML or any other textual or text-based document on the web except as a sort of techie trolling.

Just go with the defaults.

Comment: Great. HTTP/S UTF-8 used. But the strings (LINQ) use UTF-16 and MySQL by default UTF-8, no? I think there is a problem.

Comment: What do you think this problem is?

Comment: Eh? I will convert EVER query to UTF-8 -.-

Comment: No, just use ADO.NET, Entity framework, Nhibernate, or some other ORM. There's no need to convert queries yourself.

Comment: Oh, and I can specify in the connector string that I will use UTF-8, then .NET will convert my UTF-16 strings to UTF-8, right?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, it's best not to even think of .NET strings as being UTF-16 much of the time (except when you have to worry about surrogates), just as being strings with the fact that they're UTF-16 being an implementation detail. Moving between that and what's going on in a database is for a database driver to worry about. Even if you WERE to decide to use something other than UTF-8 in the DB or for the HTTP, that'd be by changing a property not actually performing the encoding yourself.

Answer (score 4):

While UTF-8 uses less space than UTF-16 for English/Latin characters, with [HTTP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) the encoding used for the HTML itself is *largely irrelevant* for bandwidth usage<sup>1</sup>.

The graphs in [Compressed [UTF-8] String ins SQL Azure](http://joelfillmore.com/compressed-utf-8-strings-in-sql-azure/) indicate that larger compressed Unicode text only consumes marginally more bytes (and nowhere near "double") when using UTF-16 over UTF-8.

Since using compression more than *halved* the size of the UTF-8 encoded text, it is ultimately ensuring the correct HTTP compression (and cache) configuration that will reduce bandwidth usage - not about choosing a particular encoding<sup>1</sup>.

[image: Large String Results]
<sub>(source: [joelfillmore.com](http://joelfillmore.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/UT8-Compression-Large-Strings.png))</sub>

Different deflate implementations may perform better than that in the .NET Framework, which is far from stellar. The HTTP compression in an aspect of the HTTP server itself - e.g. see [Configuring HTTP Compression in IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771003(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

<sup>1</sup>Bandwidth requirements aside, some ["consider UTF-16 as harmful"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful)  and recommend that ["UTF-8 should be used everywhere"](https://utf8everywhere.org/). Also see [Encode your XML documents in UTF-8
(Hint: Size has nothing to do with it)](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-utf8/).

Answer (score 2):

You look at quite an irrelevant part when it comes to band width (and actually the other answers above follow the wrong assupmtion). The text content of a web page makes just a few percent of all the web traffic, even small images take a few kilobytes of data; an average avatar image is bigger than all the text content. And also JavaScript normally costs more traffic than the text.

Hence make sure that your encoding is fit for the textual requirements of your page, do not worry about band width here.